What does the phrase, "Distribution of a random variable" really mean?
I am a student from a maths background and this year I was takin a course on Probability and Statistics. For reference,  I am following the book, "Introduction to Probability Models" by S Ross.
Often in the book, I found the following phrase is used, "... distribution of a random variable ...". Of course, the book defines what's a cumulative distribution function of a random variable is, but I think that it may refer to either or both of these things:

It refers to the cumulative distribution function (cdf) of a random variable (RV)
It refers to the type of the RV, i.e. whether the RV is a normal RV, Binomial RV, Geometric RV, Poisson RV, Uniform RV, etc.

Am I really correct with my interpretations?
For reference, I will attach some images of how this phrase is used sometimes in the book. Here it goes:

It seems they really going on a logic, which says, "Okay, so we found the MGF of X+Y to be matching with the MGF of a binomial RV and now, since the MGF uniquely determines the distribution of the RV(, here's the binomial distribution is being referred to) so, yes, X+Y is a binomial RV".

Here, it seems that they are referring to the cdf of the RV.

I believe there is no difference between the two. There is no rigorous way to formalize "type of random variable" except by saying "the same type means the same CDF". Therefore, you can also say that "the moment-generating function uniquely determines the CDF" and so on.

@YvesDaoust So, my interpretations are correct, right?

@MykolaPochekai Are you saying that my interpretations are accurate?

@ThomasFinley Not exactly. If you put it that way, I'm saying that the second interpretation doesn't make sense to me, as there is no mathematical definition of "type of RV". That is why the second interpretation should be avoided.

@MykolaPochekai But my 2nd interpretation was from the 1st image in the original post. Can you please take a look at it?

@ThomasFinley I looked on it, there is nothing about types on the screenshot, this is, I believe, part of your interpretation. By the way, after your first green highlight there is a sentence "that is, there is one-to-one correspondence between the moment generating function and the distribution function of a random variable". This is how your green-highlighted sentence should be readed.

Have you had any measure theory? Roughly speaking, a measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb R$ is a function that maps subsets of $\mathbb R$ into nonnegative numbers, and that is countably additive. It is a generalization of the concept of nonnegative function, since if you are given a function $\rho\colon \mathbb R\to [0,\infty)$, letting
$$
\mu=\rho\,dx$$
defines a measure via the assignment
$$
\mu(A)=\int_A \rho(x)\,dx.$$
For example,
$$
\mu=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\,dx$$
is the Gaussian measure $N(0, 1)$.

When you are given an $\mathbb R$-valued random variable $X$, its distribution is the unique measure $\mu_X$ that satisfies
$$
\mu_X((a, b])=\mathbb P(a<X\le b).$$
It is the mathematical concept that describes how $X$ takes values in $\mathbb R$, how distributed these values are. Now, it turns out that $\mu_X$ is uniquely determined by its cumulative distribution function
$$
F_X(t)=\mu_X((-\infty, t]), $$
which has the advantage of being a function, not a measure, hence a conceptually simpler object. Therefore, when people speak of "a random variable having distribution blah", that equivalently refers to the actual distribution or to the cumulative distribution function.

Should be $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$ for standard gaussian measure

@Andrew: thanks, typo.

@GiuseppeNegro Actually I've no idea about measure theory, neither did I ever hear jargons like "countably additive". Can you please explain my questions in a bit simpler manner? (If that's at all possible).

@ThomasFinley: A function $\mu$ defined on subsets of $\mathbb R$ is countably additive if, given a countable family $A_1, A_2, \ldots$ of disjoint subsets of $\mathbb R$, it holds that $\mu(\bigcup A_n)=\sum_n \mu(A_n)$. Which is exactly what happens with probabilities of independent events. This is the mathematical formalization of that concept.

The distribution is a function, but it is not the CDF (nor the probability density function or probability mass function).
Let $X$ be a real-valued random variable with cumulative distribution function $F$ whose input is a single real number and whose output is the probability that $X$ is less than the input.
For example,
$$F(2) = 0.8$$
means that
$$P(X \leq 2)=0.8$$
The distribution of $X$ is a function $\mu$ which, like $F$, outputs a probability. But unlike $F$, its input is a set of real numbers. The output is the probability that $X$ falls in the input set.
For example
$$\mu([1,2])=0.5$$
means that
$$P(1 \leq X \leq 2)=0.5$$
The notation $[1,2]$ above is the interval from 1 to 2, which is the set of all real numbers between 1 and 2, including 1.01, 1.001, 1.411421, and so on.
Notice that if you know $F$, you can use it to work out values of $\mu$. For example, if you know that $F(2)=.8$ and $F(1)=.3$, then you could calculate $\mu([1,2])$ as follows
$$\mu([1,2])=P(1 \leq X \leq 2)$$
$$= P(X\leq2) - P(X\leq 1)$$
$$= F(2) - F(1)$$
$$= 0.8-0.3=0.5$$
Since you can always work out values of $\mu$ from values of $F$ (and vice versa), it is enough to know just one of them. The two functions are just different ways of characterizing the same information about $X$. The same goes for probability mass functions and density functions. Therefore, it is common to refer to any of these functions as the "distribution" of a random variable.
But if we are speaking formally, then $\mu$ is the distribution.

To put it simply, a distribution is the information needed to fully determine any statistical properties of a given random variable $X$, such as "how likely is it for $X$ to lie between $a$ and $b$" or "what is the average of $X$", etc.
There are several ways of encoding this information, with some working for any type of distribution while others only for specific types. Any of these encoding schema are equivalent whenever they are defined, so they can be equally considered as a description of a distribution:

Cumulative Distribution Function. This encodes the information of a distribution in terms of the function $F(x) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq x)$. It can be proved that any other probability-related questions can be answered once we perfectly know this function.

Characteristic Function. This is a function defined by $\varphi(t) = \mathbb{E}[e^{itX}]$, where $i$ is the imaginary number. Again, it can be proved that this function encodes all the necessary information, albeit indirectly, to reconstruct any probability for $X$.

Pushforward Measure. Intuitively speaking, this is the "ideal probability histogram" for many, many independent samples, all of which are identically distributed as $X$. It is defined as the function that assigns to each event $A$ the value $\mu(A) = \mathbb{P}(X \in A)$. Since it specifies the distribution in terms of a measure, an extremely powerful and general language for dealing with quantities distributed over spaces, it is often considered as "the" definition of the distribution of a random variable.

Moment Generating Function. This is a function defined by $M(s) = \mathbb{E}[e^{sX}]$. Unlike the three types of encoding schemes above, this does not always exist for an arbitrary distribution $X$. However, when it does exist, it has the ability to uniquely specify a distribution.

Probability Mass/Density Function. In some cases, the distribution of $X$ can be encoded via its density (although this is not always possible). I suppose you may already be familiar with these two, so I'll skip their descriptions.


